# Opencv inRange: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, opencv

Estoy intentando hacer un script que lea la webcam y aplique una mascara para unicamente mostrar algo rojo, el problema es que cuando aplico la funcion cv2.inRange con dos valores HSV me da error

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Codigo:

```
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)   

rojo_bajo = np.array([3,100,100])
rojo_alto = np.array([5,100,100])

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    framedit = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    _, thresh = cv2.inRange(framedit, rojo_bajo, rojo_alto)

    cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
    cv2.imshow("framedit", framedit)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.inRage` sólo regresa un valor, en este caso la mascara de segmentación obtenida por aplicar ambos umbrales. Intenta con un único valor de retorno:

```
mask = cv2.inRange(framedit, rojo_bajo, rojo_alto)
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
```